# Error "Could not load connection type oracle URI has an authority component " when trying to add new connection in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper

When I try to add a new connection in Sql developer its throwing an error **"Could not load connection type oracle URI has an authority component"** [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzIVb.png)

After clicking on **OK** on the error prompt, it opens the add new connections window but the TNS entry section is not available. [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOcPw.png)

When I go to Preferences->Database->Advanced to check whether the TNS path is correct or not, I see the exception there also.[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxk7d.png)

I am using SQL Developer v18.4 and Oracle 12c

Answer (score 0):

'Install' SQL Developer to a directory on your machine that's not a UNC path, like put it in c:\sqldev or /users/home/jeff/sqldev

Comment: I have installed it in D:\softs\sqldev which I hope is not UNC path but still getting the error.

Comment: Also I was using sql developer(installed in D:\softs\sqldev) from long time and it was not at all giving error. Then suddenly it started throwing error when I try to add new connection.

Comment: no, that should be fine...assuming D is a local drive. can you try renaming your system18.4 directory - it will be under your Windows User .AppData directory, and then roaming profiles and SQL Developer

Comment: Rename "SQL Developer" folder as what? also I can see 2 folders in roaming profiles. One as "SQL Developer" and another as "sqldeveloper"

Comment: There's only one system 19.1... folder - rename that to something else.

Comment: Yes its working, but after renaming the folder, when I start the SQL Developer, a new system 18.4.... folder got created and all the previous saved connections and preferences were lost.

Comment: @TarunMittal - yes, renaming the folder RESETS your config. Now that it's working, if you want to shut it down, and then copy your connections over, you can see if the problem resurfaces or not

Comment: I exported all the connections, then I renamed the system 18.4... folder and then I imported back all the connections. Its working fine now and also I got back all the previously saved connections as well. Thanks @thatjeffsmith

Comment: still I am unable to understand how did that URI error pop up because of system 18.4.. folder, because my installation and roaming/SQL Developer directory path are not at all UNC path. They are normal path itself..!

Answer (score 0):

Actually when ever we use to delete and install sql developer for multiple times. There will be some old references and connections still available in our system please check and remove those connection. I found them in the location as shown in the Image. After removing it will work.

[image]